# Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///p4

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '/screens/product_detail_screen.dart';

class Productitem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;

  Productitem(this.id, this.title, this.imageUrl);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
            ProductDetailScreen.routeName,
            arguments: id,
          );
        },
        child: GridTile(
          child: Image.network(
            imageUrl,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          footer: GridTileBar(
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
              onPressed: () {},
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
            ),
            title: Text(
              title,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
              onPressed: () {},
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My Product Item file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/product.dart';

class ProductsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _items = [
    Product(
      id: 'p1',
      title: 'Red Shirt',
      description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
      price: 29.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p2',
      title: 'Trousers',
      description: 'A nice pair of trousers.',
      price: 59.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg/512px-Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p3',
      title: 'Yellow Scarf',
      description: 'Warm and cozy - exactly what you need for the winter.',
      price: 19.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://live.staticflickr.com/4043/4438260868_cc79b3369d_z.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p4',
      title: 'A Pan',
      description: 'Prepare any meal you want.',
      price: 49.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg/1024px-Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg',
    ),
  ];

  List<Product> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  void addProduct() {
    // _item.add();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

My Provider File
I have checked all the possible options but it is throwing the same error on and on.
this is a grid view of the product and the grid view is covered by image URL and image URL is imported in another file called product grid file and that file is totally fine I have also checked the link and the link also seems fine I guess the issue is in the first set of code for reference I have also provided the provider file which handles some dummy data.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure u put the right property in the imageview because it seems that you are using id property not imageUrl

Comment: thanks i fixed it right after I pitched this question on stackOverflow\